# Create custom entity with an attached field

Tags: entities

I need create a **Table** to store one text field for node, attach input for this field to all **node add/edit forms** and **store/update/delete** its value in database on all appropriate node operations.  (*Do NOT use Field API*).

How can I do that?

Any ideas?

Comment: you must implement whole process all the way down. Create module, `hook_schema()` to create table. `hook_form_alter()` to override all forms. `hook_form_submit()` to store your data to db. Why whitout Field Api?